# How can i add an formcollection to an string array in c#

Tags: arrays, string, c#-4.0

Hi all i have an string[] of form collection which looks like this

```
string[] formCollSkuOptionValueId=form.GetValues("txtskuopvaluetid");
string[] formCollSkuOptionNames=form.GetValues("txtSkuoptionName");
string[] formCollSkuOptionValues=form.GetValues("txSkuoptionvalues");
```

the values in this formcollection loooks like this

```
formCollSkuOptionNames={color,color,color,size,size,size,fit,fit}
formCollSkuOptionValueId={37,38,39,40,41,42,50,51}
formCollSkuOptionValues={Red,Black,Blue,X,Xl,XXl,Regular,Fit}
```

what i have to do is, i have to concatenate the `formCollSkuOptionValues` where ever the option names are same 
like this

I want the results to be in array like this

```
string[] SkuOptionValueId={37_38_39},{40_41_42},{50_51}
string[] SkuOptionValues={Red_Black_Blue},{X_Xl_XXl},{Regular_Fit}
```

how can i do this, can any one help me do this is what i have been trying  to do is

```
string SkuOptionName = string.Empty;
string SkuOptionValues = string.Empty;
string SkuOptionValueId = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < formCollSkuOptionValues.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    arrays.Clear();
    SkuOptionName = formCollSkuOptionNames[count];
    if (count != 0)
    {
        if (SkuOptionName == formCollSkuOptionNames[i])
        {
            SkuOptionValues = SkuOptionValues + formCollSkuOptionValues[i] + ",";
            SkuOptionValueId = SkuOptionValueId + formCollSkuOptionValueId[i] + ",";
        }
        arrays.Add(SkuOptionValues);
        count++;
    }
    SkuOptionValues = SkuOptionValues + formCollSkuOptionValues[i] + ",";
    SkuOptionValueId = SkuOptionValueId + formCollSkuOptionValueId[i] + ",";
    //str.Remove(str.IndexOf(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `linq` and write it this way:

```
var namesAndIndexes = formCollSkuOptionNames.Select((e, i) => new { Name = e, Index = i }).ToList();

var nameValueIds = namesAndIndexes.Select(e => new { ValueId = formCollSkuOptionValueId[e.Index], Name = e.Name});
var nameValues = namesAndIndexes.Select(e => new { Value = formCollSkuOptionValues[e.Index], Name = e.Name });

var groupNameValueIds = nameValueIds.GroupBy(e => e.Name, a => a.ValueId);
var groupNameValues = nameValues.GroupBy(e => e.Name, a => a.Value);

var skuOptionValueId = groupNameValueIds.Select(e => e.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "_" + b)).ToArray();
var skuOptionValues = groupNameValues.Select(e => e.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "_" + b)).ToArray();
```

I think it's the modern way to write it. Forget about `for` and `if` :)

Comment: Aggregate is not supported in this "var skuOptionValueId = nameValueIds.Select(e => e.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "_" + b)).ToArray();"